# LinkedIn SDK ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, linkedin-api

I am trying to integrate LinkedIn SDK in iOS using swift

I found the below code in objective-C (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/signin-with-linkedin)

```
NSString *url = [NSString initWithString:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~"];
if ([LISDKSessionManager hasValidSession]) {
    [[LISDKAPIHelper sharedInstance] getRequest:url
    success:^(LISDKAPIResponse *response) {
        // do something with response
    }
    error:^(LISDKAPIError *apiError) {
        // do something with error
    }];
]}
```

How to convert this to swift.

I am very new to swift

Comment: What have you tried and where is it failing to compile? The only thing particularly challenging here would be the block syntax and there is a lot of documentation on swift block syntax

Comment: @WillM. I tried and I am getting compile error 

if LISDKSessionManager.hasValidSession(){
            LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().getRequest(url, success: <#((LISDKAPIResponse!) -> Void)!##(LISDKAPIResponse!) -> Void#>, error: <#((LISDKAPIError!) -> Void)!##(LISDKAPIError!) -> Void#>)
        }

I am not sure how to fill the second and third parameter

Answer (score 2):

```
var url = NSString(string:"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~")

if LISDKSessionManager.hasValidSession {
    LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().getRequest(url, success: {
        response in
        //Do something with the response
    }, error: {
        error in
        //Do something with the error
    })
}
```

This (I think its correct) is the translated version. I don't know Objective-C, I just used my knowledge of Swift to try and figure this out.

Have you learned about closures yet? If not, I don't recommend using SDKs like the LinkedIn one because they rely on closures for many networking requests. I'd check out [Treehouse Inc.](http://teamtreehouse.com), a coding course site which offers great courses on closures in Swift (along with a bunch of other stuff).

Answer (score -1):

```
var url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~"

if LISDKSessionManager.hasValidSession() 
{
 try? LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().getRequest(url, success: {(_ response: LISDKAPIResponse) -> Void in
        // do something with response
    })
}
```

this is in swift 4

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.